# не могу открыть изображение или видео с помощью cv::imread на C++, VS22

Tags: c++, исключения, opencv

Вот код:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"


using namespace cv;
void main()
{
    std::string path = "test.jpg";
    cv::Mat img = imread(path);
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

Вылезает исключение ошибки доступа на моменте вывода изображения в окно (imshow). В отладчике видел, что изображение даже не считывается (imread).

Пробовал менять путь, пихал в корень диска, пробовал другие изображения, пнг, жпг, пробовал разные версии openCV (4.5.5, 4.6.0, 4.7.0), изначально пытался прочесть видео (cv::VideoCapture(filename)), тоже не считывается.

Visual studio 2022, windows 11

В чём может быть проблема и что ещё попробовать?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте открывать .bmp указывая абсолютный путь. И убедитесь, что библиотеки собраны с настройками, совместимыми с настройками вашего проекта.

Comment: если при отладке Working Directory не задан, то он будет debug или release

Comment: спасибо за ответ всем, ребяты! проблема оказалась супербанальной - указал не ту версию opencv (дебаг вместо релизной)...